# How to calculate mean of each bin after using `numpy.digitize` to split up a NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

I have an input array which is being split up into bins and I want to calculate the mean for those bins. Let's assume the following example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1.4, 2.6, 0.7, 1.1])
```

Which is being split up into bins by [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html):

```
>>> bins = np.arange(0, 2 + 1)
>>> indices = np.digitize(a, bins)
>>> indices
array([2, 3, 1, 2])
```

This does exactly what I expect it to do as you can see here more explicitly:

```
>>> for i in range(len(bins)):
...     f"bin where {i} <= x < {i + 1} contains {a[indices == i + 1]}"
... 
'bin where 0 <= x < 1 contains [0.7]'
'bin where 1 <= x < 2 contains [1.4 1.1]'
'bin where 2 <= x < 3 contains [2.6]'
```

However, now I want to get the mean for each bin. Doing it the non-NumPy way with a `for` loop would be like this:

```
>>> b = np.array([a[indices == i + 1].mean() for i in range(len(bins))])
>>> b
array([0.7 , 1.25, 2.6 ])
```

But using a `for` loop for this appears neither elegant (pythonic), nor efficient, as the list will have to be converted into a NumPy array with `np.array` afterwards.

What's the NumPy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, this is `bincount`:

```
np.bincount(indices-1,a)/np.bincount(indices-1)
```

Output:

```
array([0.7, 1.25, 2.6])
```

Answer (score 0):

The numpy way for doing this would be numpy.mean() as function